# How do I link codeblocks to a video game (e.g. half life) executable( the host application)?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I build a project in codeblocks and i'm trying to run it. It is a dll for an already made game called Half life. I'm using codeblocks to make a mod for the game, so i'm looking at the code, trying to run within the game. I get this message when i run it "You must select a host application to "run" a library". So what's the option in the codeblocks IDE where i can tell codeblocks to go to the game's folder and grab the .exe? Not talking about the ">Type console" solution I seen.

I'm afraid to try anything, i don't want to mess up anything. I don't know what the settings mean and I can't find any explanations to the settings.

Comment: If the game has a method for loading mods then you should use that. If not you'll have to figure out another way to load it, perhaps DLL injection or by hijacking and detouring one of the DLL file the game loads itself. None of these have anything to do with the IDE or editor you used to write the code.

Comment: I found a few guides on making mods for Half Life, and they are all using Visual Studio. Is there some reason you are not using it, even though it is free?

Comment: First figure out how to do it from the console. Then figure out how to make CB run the same console command.

Comment: I ran it in console, but i get an error, that's in the code itself, which it shouldn't (typedef __int16 int16; "_int16 does not name a type"). I'm looking for an option to ignore the messages, but i can't find anything. I seen the tutorials and I'll probably switch to visual studio whenever i'll be able to run windows 10, since codeblocks seems pretty limited.

Comment: Sounds like you have a compiler error, you'll need to fix that before running your code. To run it you'll need to attach to run half life, I'm sure the code blocks documentation will cover how to do that

Comment: *"looking for an option to ignore the messages"* That's basically saying "my engine is making weird noises, how do I soundproof it". You need to understand the error and fix it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

This usually happens when an application is written in one IDE and runs in another